# gulp-notify: [sass error!] помогите плиз

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, npm

**Проблема собственно вот в чем**

[image: ошибка]

Дали сборку другого разработчика. Не могу запустить чтоб всё было в норме. У другого разраба всё работало.

я вообще не вижу файл который импортируется. Почему тогда у того разраба всё работает. Тут куча тасков, которые я ваще не понимаю. Вообщем обьясните плиз, чо происходит..и как сделать чтоб работало

Там вроде есть таск по сборке svg файлов. Может что-то не работает. Я просто первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой сборкой.

Даже не знаю что предоставить в этой ситуации.. вот gulpfile.js

```
"use strict";

var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
    reload       = browserSync.reload,
    del          = require('del'),
    pug          = require('gulp-pug'),
    cache        = require('gulp-cache'),
    notify       = require('gulp-notify'),
    imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    useref       = require('gulp-useref'),
    svgSprite    = require('gulp-svg-sprite'),
    pugData      = require('./app/data/pug_data.json'),
    postcss      = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    assets       = require('postcss-assets'),
    sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
    comments     = require('postcss-discard-comments'),
    mqpack       = require('css-mqpacker'),
    csso         = require('gulp-csso'),
    spritesmith  = require('gulp.spritesmith'),
    merge        = require('merge-stream'),
    iconFont     = require('gulp-iconfont'),
    iconFontCss  = require('gulp-iconfont-css'),
    sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

//---------------------------------------SYNC

gulp.task('sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./app/"
        },
        open: false,
        notify: false
    });
});

//---------------------------------------ASSETS

gulp.task('assets', ['imgInline', 'svgCssCom', 'svgCssMain', 'svgSymbol', 'svgCssServ', 'libsCss', 'smithEditions'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        './node_modules/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js',
        './libs/jquery.sticky.js',
        './node_modules/inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js',
        './node_modules/inputmask/dist/min/inputmask/inputmask.phone.extensions.min.js',
        './node_modules/inputmask/dist/min/inputmask/phone-codes/phone.min.js',
        './node_modules/inputmask/dist/min/inputmask/phone-codes/phone-ru.min.js',
        './node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js',
        './node_modules/jquery-sticky/jquery.sticky.js'
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/libs/js/'))
});


gulp.task('libsCss', function () {

    var processors = [
        comments(),
        assets({
            basePath   : './app/',
            loadPaths  : ['./images/', './fonts/'],
            baseUrl    : '/local/',
            cachebuster: true,
            relative   : true
        }),
        // mqpack({
        //  sort: true
        // })
    ];
    return gulp.src(['./app/sass/libs/**/*'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/libs/css/'));

});

//------------------------------------ICONFONT

gulp.task('iconfont', function () {
    var fontName = 'icon-font';

    return gulp.src('./app/images/iconfont/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(iconFontCss({
            fontName  : fontName,
            path      : './app/templates/font.sass',
            targetPath: '../sass/_iconfont.sass'
        }))
        .pipe(iconFont({
            fontHeight: 1001,
            normalize : true,
            fontName  : fontName,
            formats   : ['ttf', 'woff', 'woff2']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/fonts'));
});

//---------------------------------------PUG

gulp.task('pug', function () {
    gulp.src(['./app/**/*.pug', '!./app/pug/**/*'])
        .pipe(pug({
            locals: pugData,
            pretty: true
        }))
        .on('error', notify.onError({
            message: "<%= error.message %>",
            title  : "Pug error!"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'));
});

//---------------------------------------CSS

gulp.task('css', function () {
    var processors = [
        comments(),
        assets({
            basePath   : './app/',
            loadPaths  : ['./images/', './fonts/'],
            baseUrl    : '/local/',
            cachebuster: true,
            relative   : true
        }),
        mqpack({
            sort: true
        })
    ];
    return gulp.src(['./app/sass/**/*', '!./app/sass/libs/**/*'], {
        dot: true
    })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .on('error', notify.onError({
            message: "<%= error.message %>",
            title  : "sass error!"
        }))
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .on('error', notify.onError({
            message: "<%= error.message %>",
            title  : "postcss error!"
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css/'));

});

//---------------------------------------IMAGES

gulp.task('smithEditions', function () {
    var spriteData = gulp.src('./app/images/sprites/editions/*')
        .pipe(spritesmith({
            imgName: 'sprite-editions.png',
            cssName: '_sprite-editions.sass',
            imgPath: '../../images/sprite-editions.png'
        }));

    var imgStream = spriteData.img
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/images/'));

    var cssStream = spriteData.css
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/sass/'));

    return merge(imgStream, cssStream);
});


gulp.task('img', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/images/**/*', '!./app/images/sprites/**/*', '!./app/images/inline/**/*', '!./app/images/tmp/**/*'])
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([
            imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
            imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
            imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 3}),
            imagemin.svgo({plugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]})
        ])))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/images/'));
});

gulp.task('imgInline', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/images/inline/app/*'])
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([
            imagemin.svgo({plugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]})
        ])))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/images/inline/dist'));
});


gulp.task('svgCssCom', function () {

    return gulp.src('app/images/sprites/common/*.svg')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([
            imagemin.svgo({plugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]})
        ])))
        .pipe(svgSprite({
            mode     : {
                css: {
                    dest  : './',
                    sprite: '../images/sprite-css_com',
                    bust  : false,
                    layout: 'diagonal',
                    render: {
                        scss: {
                            dest    : '../sass/_sprite-css_com.scss',
                            template: "app/templates/sprite-css_com.hbs"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            variables: {
                mapname: "icons"
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/images/'));

});

gulp.task('svgCssMain', function () {

    return gulp.src('app/images/sprites/main-page/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([
            imagemin.svgo({plugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]})
        ])))
        .pipe(svgSprite({
            mode     : {
                css: {
                    dest  : './',
                    sprite: '../images/sprite-css_main',
                    bust  : false,
                    layout: 'diagonal',
                    render: {
                        scss: {
                            dest    : '../sass/_sprite-css_main.scss',
                            template: "./app/templates/sprite-css_main.hbs"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            variables: {
                mapname: "main"
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/images/'));

});

gulp.task('svgCssServ', function () {

    return gulp.src('app/images/sprites/services/**/*.svg')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([
            imagemin.svgo({plugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]})
        ])))
        .pipe(svgSprite({
            mode     : {
                css: {
                    dest  : './',
                    sprite: '../images/sprite-css_serv',
                    bust  : false,
                    layout: 'diagonal',
                    render: {
                        scss: {
                            dest    : '../sass/_sprite-css_serv.scss',
                            template: "./app/templates/sprite-css_main.hbs"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            variables: {
                mapname: "serv"
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/images/'));

});

gulp.task('svgSymbol', function () {

    return gulp.src('./app/images/sprites/symbol/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite({
            mode     : {
                symbol: {
                    dest  : '',
                    sprite: 'sprite-symbol.svg',
                    render: {
                        scss: {
                            dest: '../sass/_sprite-symbol.scss'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            variables: {
                mapname: "ic-symbol"
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/images/'));

});

//---------------------------------------CLEAN

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del.sync('./dist/');
});

gulp.task('cleanCss', function () {
    return del.sync('./dist/css/');
});

//---------------------------------------WATCH

gulp.task('default', ['sync', 'css', 'pug'], function () {
    gulp.watch('./app/sass/**/*.sass', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('./app/css/styles.css', reload);
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.pug', ['pug']);
    gulp.watch('./app/index.html', reload);
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.js', reload);
});

//---------------------------------------BUILD

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'img', 'pug', 'css', 'assets'], function () {

    var processors = [
        comments({
            removeAll: true
        }),
        assets({
            basePath   : './app/',
            loadPaths  : ['./images/', './fonts/'],
            baseUrl    : '/local/',
            cachebuster: true,
            relative   : false
        }),
        mqpack({
            sort: true
        }),
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'not ie <= 9', '> 1% in RU']
        })
    ];

    gulp.src(['./app/sass/**/*'], {
        dot: true
    })
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(csso({
            restructure: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));

    gulp.src('./app/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));

    gulp.src('./app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref({
            noconcat: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));

    gulp.src('./app/images/sprite.svg')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/images/'));

});

gulp.task('buildCss', ['css'], function () {
    var processors = [
        comments({
            removeAll: true
        }),
        assets({
            basePath   : './app/',
            loadPaths  : ['./images/', './fonts/'],
            baseUrl    : '/local/',
            cachebuster: true,
            relative   : false
        }),
        mqpack({
            sort: true
        }),
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'not ie <= 10']
        })
    ];
    gulp.src(['./app/sass/**/*'], {
        dot: true
    })
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(csso({
            restructure: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там же написано что не чего импортировать ..то есть нету этих файлов и не чего импортировать в `sprite-css_com`

Comment: @MaximLensky а что надо сделать то, чтоб работало? проблема в том что он не компилируется и открывается просто html страница без стилей и скриптов.

Comment: надо наверно создать эти файлы и именно в тех директориях в которых они указаны